# Contact Image -Less resolution in android

Tags: android, image, resolution, android-contacts

I have retrieved the android phone contact image and stored it in arraylist like the below.

```
id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
String photoWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
String[] photoParams = new String[] {id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
Cursor photoCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, photoWhere, photoParams, null);                     
if(photoCursor!=null && photoCursor.getCount()>0)
{
 while(photoCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        byte[] contactPhoto = photoCursor.getBlob(photoCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO));                        
        if(contactPhoto!=null)
        {
            mContactImage="data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(contactPhoto, Base64.NO_WRAP);                   
            sContactImageArray.add(mContactImage);
        }                                           
   }
}                                 
photoCursor.close();
```

Then I have pass this base64 string into javascript and displayed as a image. But the image resolution is poor. This not same as the image stored in the phone contact. How can I retrieve the contact image with 100% quality.?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to these fields. It seems that if the contact avatar is set from local photo, you might have a chance to get a high-resolution version.

```
    /**
     * Reference to the row in the data table holding the photo.  A photo can
     * be referred to either by ID (this field) or by URI (see {@link #PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI}
     * and {@link #PHOTO_URI}).
     * If PHOTO_ID is null, consult {@link #PHOTO_URI} or {@link #PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI},
     * which is a more generic mechanism for referencing the contact photo, especially for
     * contacts returned by non-local directories (see {@link Directory}).
     *
     * <P>Type: INTEGER REFERENCES data(_id)</P>
     */
    public static final String PHOTO_ID = "photo_id";

    /**
     * Photo file ID of the full-size photo.  If present, this will be used to populate
     * {@link #PHOTO_URI}.  The ID can also be used with
     * {@link ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto#CONTENT_URI} to create a URI to the photo.
     * If this is present, {@link #PHOTO_ID} is also guaranteed to be populated.
     *
     * <P>Type: INTEGER</P>
     */
    public static final String PHOTO_FILE_ID = "photo_file_id";

    /**
     * A URI that can be used to retrieve the contact's full-size photo.
     * If PHOTO_FILE_ID is not null, this will be populated with a URI based off
     * {@link ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto#CONTENT_URI}.  Otherwise, this will
     * be populated with the same value as {@link #PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI}.
     * A photo can be referred to either by a URI (this field) or by ID
     * (see {@link #PHOTO_ID}). If either PHOTO_FILE_ID or PHOTO_ID is not null,
     * PHOTO_URI and PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI shall not be null (but not necessarily
     * vice versa).  Thus using PHOTO_URI is a more robust method of retrieving
     * contact photos.
     *
     * <P>Type: TEXT</P>
     */
    public static final String PHOTO_URI = "photo_uri";

    /**
     * A URI that can be used to retrieve a thumbnail of the contact's photo.
     * A photo can be referred to either by a URI (this field or {@link #PHOTO_URI})
     * or by ID (see {@link #PHOTO_ID}). If PHOTO_ID is not null, PHOTO_URI and
     * PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI shall not be null (but not necessarily vice versa).
     * If the content provider does not differentiate between full-size photos
     * and thumbnail photos, PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI and {@link #PHOTO_URI} can contain
     * the same value, but either both shall be null or both not null.
     *
     * <P>Type: TEXT</P>
     */
    public static final String PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI = "photo_thumb_uri";
```

Comment: Thansks for the response. Could you please post the code to get the URI of the contact image.?